# Heat Equation - Rectangular

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, computational-physics, diffusion

so I'm a little confused. I have the following 2-d heat equation,
$$
\rho c\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=k\left(\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial y^2}\right)+Q,
$$

applied to a rectangular, perfectly insulated piece of metal. Now I would like to model a constant point heat source at the centre of this at a particular temperature.

My question is do I have to obtain an equation for $Q$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ that models this heat source? Or am I able to put $Q$ at a constant value and then use a boundary condition that defines the temperature at the centre to be the temperature of the heat source?

Comment: To be clear, do you want to set a temperature or a heat flux at this heat source?

Comment: I'm not honestly not too sure. I'm trying to model a heat source and show the effect that this heat source has on the temperature over time on the entire metal. What would you recommend?

Comment: This is not the equation for a constant point heat source, unless Q is multiplied by the radial Dirac delta function.  With a constant point heat source, the temperature at the location of the heat source is singular (infinite).  So, it is not possible to specify (or determine) the temperature at the point heat source.

Comment: Would a surface heat source be suitable with this equation?

Comment: @nluigi , if I were to use a point heat source could I not just pick a value for Q and multiply it by the dirac delta function and use that?

Comment: Answering your most recent question first:  short answer, yes.  But before trying that, what are the boundary conditions at the edges of the plate, and the initial temperature condition for the plate?

Comment: And are you trying to solve this numerically or analytically?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I am solving numerically. (with finite differnece methods in MATLAB). Initial temperature of the plate is uniform at 15C. Plate is perfectly insulated and so du/dX and du/dY at edges are 0.

Comment: OK.  Then you're only going to get a rough approximation to the temperature field in the close vicinity to the point source.  You are going to be applying a constant heating rate over a grid square centered at the grid point of the source.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Hmm. So can I not just say that Q = Qconstant*DiracDelta?

Comment: Not if you're doing it numerically.  There, when you integrate over the target grid box, you end up with $Q/(\Delta y\Delta x)$ where Q is the total rate of heating flow, and this is the heating rate per unit area.

Comment: So essentially, because we can't really specify exact points we choose a small grid that essentially acts like a point source? So how exactly do I modify the PDE up there now?

Comment: Yes.  In your numerical method, you only add the heat Q at one grid point within the rectangular domain.  At all other grid points, it is equal to zero.

Comment: Ah. so I basically define say Q(i=0, j=0) = Qconstant value and everywhere else it will be zero.